# Loading page in ReactJS and constant reloading component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, overlay

In my project I have some components, one of them is a `div` which consists several other components and is a button and its use is like a menu.

Trying to make a loading page overlayed to prevent actions during the charge of components, I modified my code:

1) Including in the constructor:

```js
this.state = {
    isLoaded: false
}
```

2) Adding a componentDidMount() method:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        isLoaded: true
    })
}
```

3) Changing the render method:

```js
const isLoaded = this.state.isLoaded;
if (!isLoaded) {
    document.getElementById("loadingPageHTML").style.display = "inline-block";
    return(
        <p className = "noShowIt"> Hola </p>
    );
} else {
    document.getElementById("loadingPageHTML").style.display = "none";
    return (
        <div className="MainMenuButtons">
        ...
}
```

But when I debug on my browser I see that when I press one of these buttons, the flow is always enter in the render method of this component, so, the loading page `display` is always `inline-block` status even if the second component (with the same state and conditions) isn't loaded.

What's the way to develop a loading lay with a good behaviour?

Is it possible to do it in a similar way as `ajaxStart` function in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of mixing react components with an older style of web development.

You'd want to render a loading component or your content components based on the `isLoaded` state rather then using css and dom selectors. for example:

`render () => (!isLoaded) ? <LoadingComponent /> : <Content />;`

```
render() {
   if (!isLoaded) {
     return <LoadingComponent />;
   } else {
     return (<div> ... </div>);
   }
}
```

When the state changes the components being rendered will automatically update

Comment: The problem generated with this way is the HTML tag where the LoadingComponent will be rendered... It will not be in the parent div (inmediately below of the body one), it will be in the same div that Content Component and probably it would be a child tag and in this case the other components could be modified behaviour that I'm trying to avoid...